# Android generate sound

Tags: android, audio

I wrote this code to generate sound but I am not able to stop the sound. When I press start button it generates sound, but nothing happens when I press end button. Can somebody tell me what is wrong ?

```
private final int duration = 5; // seconds
private final int sampleRate = 8000;
private final int numSamples = duration * sampleRate;
private final double sample[] = new double[numSamples];
private final double freqOfTone = 250; // hz
private final byte generatedSnd[] = new byte[2 * numSamples];
Handler handler = new Handler();
private AudioTrack audioTrack;
private boolean play = false;
Button btnstart;
Button btnstop;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnstart= (Button)findViewById(R.id.StartSound);
    btnstop= (Button)findViewById(R.id.EndSound);
    btnstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, numSamples,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            play=true;
            audioTrack.play();
          //  playSound();
            genTone();

        }
    });
btnstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    stopPlaying();
    audioTrack= new AudioTrack(AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM,8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,numSamples,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    audioTrack.play();


    }
});
    }



 void genTone(){
    // fill out the array
    while(play){
        for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
            //  float angular_frequency =
            sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate/freqOfTone));
        }
        int idx = 0;

        // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
        // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
        for (double dVal : sample) {
            short val = (short) (dVal * 32767);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
        }
        audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, numSamples);
    }
}

  void stopPlaying() {
    if (audioTrack !=null){
        audioTrack.stop();
       audioTrack.release();
        audioTrack=null;        
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `genTone()` method is blocking the UI thread in its `while(play)` loop. No UI events such as button clicks can be processed while the UI thread is busy doing something else.

Apps with UI thread blocked get killed as "application not responding" after some time.

Consider using a background thread for your long-running tone generation loop.

Comment: So how can I remediate this problem? Thank you for your answer!